# How to Loop recipient in email Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Have tried send email to multiple recipients but only 1 data is sent:

```
function reminder(){
    $recipients= $this->user_model->view();
    var_dump($recipients[0]->email);
    $emaill = $recipients->email;
    $recipientsmail= $emaill.',';
    $email = $recipientsmail;
    $judul = 'Test Email';
    $deskripsi = 'TESt Email';

    $config = [...]; //config for email is OK

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('tes');
    $this->email->to($email); 
    $this->email->subject($judul);
    $this->email->message($deskripsi);
    $this->email->send();
    return TRUE;

}
```

is something wrong in my code?
Please Help Me

Comment: Hi, i think there are some problems in your code; for example you put `$this->email->message("$deskripsi");` but would be `$this->email->message($deskripsi);`, and if you want to send multiple emails you should send them one by one. Maybe I could help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I use to send multiple emails in codeigniter. Instead of put all the email directions in a variable (`$email`), use a `foreach` to loop the array and follow the details in the code:

```
function reminder(){
    $recipients= $this->user_model->view();
    var_dump($recipients[0]->email);

    $judul = 'Test Email';
    $deskripsi = 'This is a test';
    $emailuser = 'user123@gmial.com';//for example
    $nameuser = 'name of the user';

    $config = [...]; //config for email is OK

    $this->load->library("email");

  foreach ($recipients as $value) {
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($emailuser, $nameuser);
    $this->email->to($value->email); 
    $this->email->subject($judul);
    $this->email->message($deskripsi);
    if($this->email->send()){
        $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully."); 
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Error in sending Email."); 
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
 }
```

And with this you could send more than one email. I hope it helps you.